# How do i remove a specific element/text from an file?

Tags: python, string

I dont know what im missing, but i dont seem to be able to remove specific words in an .txt file, ive tried the .remove(), but i received error on that aswell.

```
if ans == "remove":
    x = input("Clean sheet or some particular?")

    if x == "whole":
        lista.close()
        os.remove("testsamling.txt")
    if x == "some":
        lista = open("testsamling.txt","r")
        print(lista.read())
        ans = input("Which one?")
        
        lista.truncate.index(ans)
        print("has been removed!")
```

Answer (score 1):

What you could do in the "some" `x` option is to remove the words from `str` using `replace` method and passing an empty string as a second argument to it.

```
with open("testsamling.txt","r") as f:
   s = f.read()
   updated = s.replace(ans, '')
```

You can then save the file with:

```
with open("testsamling.txt","w") as f:
   f.write(updated)
```

Answer (score 1):

[os.remove](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.remove) will delete the file.

What you're looking for is something like,

```py
element_to_remove_from_text_file = 'cat '
file_path = r'C:\my_file.txt'

with open(file_path, mode='r+') as f:
    contents = f.read()
    contents = contents.replace(element_to_remove_from_text_file, '')
    f.seek(0)
    f.write(contents)
```

Comment: I think this will require `f.seek(0)` before `f.write`. Otherwise it will append the contents at the end of file.

Comment: @LukaszWiecek you are correct!

Answer (score 0):

use the `string.replace()` method:

- open the text : `with open(file_path, mode="r") as f`
- make the file readable in python : `source_text = f.read()`
- replace the text with an empty string : `updated_text = source_text.replace(oldtext, "")`
- write the output to a new file:

  ```py
  with open(new_file_path, mode="w" as f):
      f.write(updated_text)
  ```

i went ahead and **wrote a small cli** for such a task using `click` (https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.0.x/) (only i couldn't be bothered to use an external file and just assigned some random text to the `source_text` variable :

```py
import click

source_text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt \
  esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, \
  sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."

@click.command()
@click.option("--to_remove", default=None, prompt="What do you want to delete ?", help="The text you want to remove")
def remove_text(to_remove):
    if str(to_remove) in source_text:
        updated_text = source_text.replace(to_remove, " ")
        click.echo(updated_text)
    else:
        click.echo("Your input is not in the text and could not be deleted")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    remove_text()
```